# Simple shell implementation with C in linux, fork causing infinite loop

Tags: c, linux, shell, fork

I'm trying to implement a simple shell in C and my program is causing an infinite loop and creating a ton of new processes/printing `Myshell>` before the user has a chance to enter in any commands. I can't seem to find a way to prevent this and if anyone could help that would be great! (Didn't paste the `#include` headers at top

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

    char buffer[512];
    int *status;
    size_t nargs;
    pid_t pid;
    char delim[] = "\n";

    while(1){

        pid = fork();       
        if(pid){

        printf("Myshell> ");
        fgets(buffer, 512, stdin);
        //parse(buffer, argv);

        argv[0] = strtok(buffer, delim);
        for(argc=1; argv[argc-1]; argc++){
            argv[argc] = strtok(NULL, delim);
        }       

        if(!strcmp(argv[0], "exit"))
            exit(0);

        printf("Waiting for child (%d)\n", pid);
        pid = wait(status);
        printf("Child (%d) finished\n", pid);
        exit(0);
        }else{
            if(execvp(argv[0], argv)){
                printf("error");
                exit(1);
            }else{
                exit(0);
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You need to fork after reading the command, not in the loop that reads commands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are reading command into buffer using fgets  but not from command line argument So `argv[argc]` for `argc > 1` is wrong - undefined behaviour.

When you don't pass any extra command line argument then `argv[0]` is your program name and `argv[1]` is NULL. indexing to `argv[]` for  value more then 1 causes array out of index problem.

Instead of declare `argv[]` and `argc` as main function parameter declare within main as formal variable something like:

```
int argc;
char* argv[MAX]; // max number of argument can be pass to your shell
```

One more rectification in your code, change:

```
int *status;
```

as

```
int status;
```

and accordingly correct

```
pid = wait(status);
```

as

```
pid = wait(&status);
```

Comment: what's the best way to make the program wait to get command line arguments before trying to create processes?

Comment: @user2739431 Read this and get some idea [Writing Your Own Shell](http://linuxgazette.net/111/ramankutty.html) good starting tutorial

Comment: @user2739431 If you want to create very good [code learn from this](http://www.ladweb.net/src/ladsh4.c.html) it veryu nice book

Comment: Thanks I fixed the problem with the infinite loop, but now when I just try to do ls it prints 

"Waiting for child (%pid) 
Segmentation fault (core dumped)"

Comment: @user2739431 couldn't find Note to pass `argv` in `execvp(argv[0], argv)` `argv` should be NULL terminated add `argv[argc] = NULL;` after for loop.